# find char at index in MIPS

Tags: indexing, mips

I'm trying to find the index of a specific character, so if the char was 'd', the index would be 3

```
   indexOf:     
        slt $t0, $a2, $t2   #while index of char is <= length
        bne $t0, $zero, end2    #if not equal to any letter in string, return -1
        addi $a0, $a0, 1    #goes through string
        addi $t1, $t1, 1    #add one to t1 for length tracker
        j indexOf       #looop

end2:   
    li $v0, -1      #return -1 if char not in string
    jr $ra      #return to ra
```

Comment: And the question is..? Just read characters until you find the one you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIPS how to find a character and an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721773/mips-how-to-find-a-character-and-an-index)

Comment: but how do I know if I've found it?

Comment: By comparing the value you just read from memory against what you are looking for.